# How to build android flexible stack layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

This layout issue that I faced with today seems not very easy to me.

Here it is: I have a text with a number in the middle that should be modified *(Ex: Delete records older than **10** days)*. I want users to modify this number directly in text. For this, I have TextView + EditText + TextView [image: Layout]
But on smaller screen sizes, if the second TextView doesn't fit, this can be a disaster. So, I want my layout to do something like this: [image]
In general, I want the behavior similar to text behavior when it is splitting in multiple lines.
I think I have seen such behavior somewhere else (stack layout or something), but how to do that in native android app? Is there a layout for this?

Comment: There are several options available, although I would probably just define a separate layout inside a different `/layout` resource directory -> [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap your views inside flexbox layout

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

add in your dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.1'
}

<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:flexWrap="wrap"
  app:alignItems="stretch"
  app:alignContent="stretch" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:layout_alignSelf="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview3"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:layout_alignSelf="flex_end"
    />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @АннаКочешкова happy to help